# How to traverse through a column in a 2D array

Tags: c

Given array A[3][2] ={(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)}

I want to traverse through the first column elements i.e 1,3,5 and next column elements, 2,4,6. All this must be done using a single pointer. How to do this?

Comment: I must perform operations on each column elements. How to do this using a single pointer?

Comment: So, you want to traverse in the given array using pointer. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 array indices, use two `for` loops.

```
uint32_t m, n, sum = 0U;
for(n = 0U; n < 2; ++n){ // For each column [n]
  for(m = 0U; m < 3; ++m){ // For each row [m] in column [n]
    sum += A[m][n];
  }
}
```

Edit: There's not really a difference when using pointers (especially once passed into a function, when it decays). But you have to deal with dereferencing the pointer. This code is more type obfuscating, and could lead one to improperly type/reference, if you don't compile with sufficient warning flags.

```
uint32_t A[3][2] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
uint32_t m, sum = 0U;
uint32_t (*pa2_n)[2];
uint32_t * p_m;
for(pa2_n = &A[0]; pa2_n < &A[3]; ++pa2_n){ // For each column [n]
  for(m = 0U; m < 2U; ++m){ // For each row [m] in column [n]
    sum += (*pa2_n)[m];
  }
  // Or
  for(p_m = &(*pa2_n)[0]; p_m < &(*pa2_n)[2]; ++p_m){ // For each row [m] in column [n]
    sum += *p_m;
  }
}
printf("Hello World %u\n", sum);
```

Comment: I want to use single pointer. I know how to perform it using array notation. But i want to use using pointer notation.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to traverse in the given array `int A[3][2]` using `single pointer` you should look at this code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[3][2] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    int *ptr = arr[0], i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%4d", *(ptr+j*2+i));
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I assume you know about the `memory representation` of a 2D array. If you don't then I'll tell you in short.

> A 2D array is stored in the computer's memory on consecutive locations, i.e. one row after another.

That is elements of `arr` in the above code, will be stored as first `1`, second `2`, and so on. Using this `*(ptr+j*2+i)` statement we are traversing through the array. In 1st iteration we are printing `ptr+0` then `ptr+2` and so on.

**Or you can make it simple by declaring a `pointer to an array`**

`int (*ptr)[2]; ptr = arr;`

and now you can access elements of `arr` using `ptr` just like a 2D array.

`printf("%4d", ptr[j][i]);` or `printf("%4d", *(*(ptr+j)+i));`

I hope you'll understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
//
// a method using only 1 pointer could rely on pointer math
//
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 2

int
main(void)
{
    int matrix[ROWS][COLS] = {
        { 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6 },
    };
    int *ptr = &matrix[0][0];

    while (1) {
        printf("%d,", *ptr);

        // point into the next row, same col
        ptr += COLS;

        // now pointing at least 1 row too many?
        if (ptr >= &matrix[ROWS][0]) {
            printf("\n");

            // at least 1 row too many, last col?
            if (ptr >= &matrix[ROWS][COLS - 1])
                break;

            // backup by total element count - 1 (first row, next col)
            ptr -= (ROWS * COLS) - 1;
        }
    }

    return (0);
}
```